# Bootstrap 4 Date Time Picker, no time selection available

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I switched from BS 3 to BS 4 and noticed date time picker stopped working.
I managed to get the date selection to work but can't seem to get the time selection to work (time icon not showing).

```
<div id="dtpStart" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" id="tbStartDateTime" class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer;" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss" />
    <label class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer" for="tbStartDateTime">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    bindCalendars();
    ....
});

function bindCalendars() {
    $('#dtpStart').unbind();
    $("#dtpStart").datetimepicker({
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
    });
    $('#dtpEnd').unbind();
    $("#dtpEnd").datetimepicker({
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
    });
}
```

I cannot find anything that resembles `data-provide="datetimepicker"`, maybe that is the problem but I have been looking and can't find a solution for this.

These are the includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/datepicker.min.css" />

<script src="assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/datatable/js/datetime-moment.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending more than a day and trying everything suggested, the issue turned out to be glyphicons in BS4.

I downloaded the new CSS [here](https://github.com/Darkseal/bootstrap4-glyphicons/blob/master/bootstrap4-glyphicons/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css), added it to the master page and "time" icon was displayed.

Hopefully this saves some people having similar issue some headache.